# Straighten loop edges on a rounded object

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying to make these loop edges straight around this rounded cube so I can easily place a shrinkwrap-like packaging and make it look good.

I tried changing the size using different methods or sliding them but I can't get them to keep the curvature of the object.

In yellow, the edge loops I have now:
[image: In yellow, the edge loops I have now]
In pink, how I'd like the edge loops to look, but keeping the main object curvature:
[image]

Comment: Did you try to select one loop and hit s, z, 0? Assuming your image is in front view.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried but the vertices move off the main object curve, what I  would like is to slide the edge but it doesn't look good either. I haven't found a solution yet but I should probably find a different approach when modelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Knife Project* tool, to cut a new edge loop.
It will perfectly follow the object's curvature.

1. Add a plane and position it where you want the cut
2. Select the plane first *and then* your object
3. Go to edit mode and use *Knife Project* with *Cut Through* checked.

*Note: The cut depends on your current view - front/side orthographic works best.*

[image]

As **Robin Betts** kindly pointed out, it's better to put the cutting geometry outside of the object, which allows to cut multiple edges at once.

*Projector parallel to viewing plane...*
[image]

*Here, a grid with its faces (only) deleted*
[image]

*.. so multiple edges cut simultaneously.*
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried the first option on my own first but even though it looks like it keeps the curvature, it does not when you turn the object around.
I will try the second one but it seems I should probably model the object again thinking how the UV will wrap first though.

Comment: Happy to help. If you get stuck anywhere, feel free to ask :).

Comment: Thanks again, that's exactly what I needed, the knife project tool worked wonders :)

Comment: @JachymMichal         Absolutely nothing wrong with your answer, (UV'd) but it's unusual to have the projector in that orientation: see [suggestion](https://imgur.com/a/HEfBtAf)

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for pointing that out, you're right :). No idea why I used it that way. Let me borrow your images to improve the answer...